# Adding event listener to an element via its class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I have the following HTML:

[image]

And I want to add an event listener for the `a` element, the one with class `k-link`. I have several other `k-link` elements on the page so I will want this specific one.

However, I started by trying to add an event listener to the `k-link` class, but without success. When I get this, I will then try to add the event listener only to this specific one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".k-link").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .k-link called.");
    });

    $(".k-link").on("click", function () {
        alert("Handler for .k-link called.");
    });
});
```

But none of these work. I searched and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974006/add-listener-to-class-or-element) but the answers there won't work on my case.

Comment: So are these anchors dynamically added to the DOM? Are they part of content iframe? Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue because at the moment, nothing explain it...

Comment: These links are added dynamically and not content of an iFrame. I would love to provide a sample that replicates the issue but I can't

Comment: Try using delegates: `$(".k-link").on("click", function`

Comment: So try delegating it: `$(document).on("click", ".k-link",  function () {
        alert("Handler for .k-link called.");
    });`  That's said, we shouldn't have to ask if elements are added dynamically, it should be in question itself...

Comment: if you want it only for the a tag, you should use: $("a.k-link").on("click",function(){//DoSomething});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: BTW, your HTML markup is invalid, a `span` cannot contains `ul` element

Comment: @chiapa Sorry but i told it because your posted link in question was refering to delegate event, so strange you didn't test it before...

Comment: @A.Wolff, I didn't know about delegate and other type of events. Anyway, I think there may be some wrong syntax on my code

Comment: Your js/jq syntax is correct. Just you shouldn't set a block element `ul` as decendant of a `span`, use `div` instead of `span`. Now is your issue fixed or not?  And again, sorry if you found any of my previous comment rude or agressive.

Comment: It is not. As for the HTML structure, it comes from Kendo UI like that, I don't write it myself. It's ok, just bear in mind that not everyone knows everything and making mistakes is in our essence

Answer (score 1):

If the other `k-link` classes are not `a` elements:

```
$("a").find(".k-link").eq(0).click(function() { ... });
```

If you want to select the `k-link` element inside the second `li`:

```
$(".k-pager-numbers").eq(0).find("li").eq(1).find(".k-link").eq(0).click(function() { ... });
```

If there is only one `k-link` element you can use this:

```
$(".k-link").eq(0).click(function() { ... });
```

And if you have more `k-link`, and want to define click handler for each, then use this:

```
$(".k-link").each(function() {
    $(this).click(function () {       
         ...
    });
});
```